# how can I show the pull-down-menu in Wireshark GUI?

Tags: user-interface, menu, toolbar, wireshark

I downloaded wireshark(3.6.3 stable release), and my laptop is MacOS ARM 64-bit.

I want to have my wireshark to show " The Menu" interface.

This image is my wireshark.
[my wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aPrY.png)

And I want to make this to have menu bar on the top.
[what I desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6xOM.png)

I have read the WireShark documents below, but there was no situation like mine.
https://www.wireshark.org/docs//wsug_html_chunked/ChUseMenuSection.html

How can I control my WireShark to appear the top menu?

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark on macOS should show its menu items in the menu bar at the top of the screen, just like any other macOS application. If it doesn't, that's a bug and should be reported on our issue tracker. The "what I desire" screenshot appears to be from Windows; that OS doesn't have a global menu bar and instead shows application menus at the top of windows.